# Too many jss style tags in the header

Tags: material-ui, jss

For SEO reasons I need to reduce the number of html tags in my page.

I notice in the header that JSS is creating duplicate style tags.

How do I merge these tags into one and/or prevent duplicate styling from reaching the header and slowing down the initial paint.

[image: duplicate tags]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you have resources that explain why the number of html tags (in the header) is important? Other than adding to the download size.

Comment: Lighthouse complains that I have over 2200 Dom elements in the tree. The recommendation is 1500 max.

Comment: How many of those 2200 dom elements are style tags?

Answer (score 1):

JSS generates style tags at runtime, this should not be a problem for SEO or is it?
For SSR there is an API to get them all in one tag for critical CSS.

Comment: I have achieved this already with ssr but Google engine also measures client side painting and performance. According to lighthouse, the site is struggling to perform well with so many Dom nodes.

Comment: I doubt its because of the style tags in the head.